# In MongoDB, how do I increase multiple values?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

The database document looks like :

```
{   "_id" : 12345,
    "options" : [ 
        {
            "no" : 1,
            "apples" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "no" : 2,
            "apples" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "no" : 3,
            "apples" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want(with one query) to increment apples on only say numbers 1 and 3, each by one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arrayFilters` for updating the fields in an array:

here is the query I wrote to update the values:

```
db.sample.update(
  {},
  {
    $inc:{
      "options.$[options].apples":1
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters:[
      {
        "options.no":{
          $in:[1,3]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

You can set your filters in `arrayFilters` according to your requirements.

For more about `arrayFilters` read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: I like how I this lets me pre-define [1,3] as a variable, that will help in this case, thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)